# Memory corruption in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

The memory was overwritten by someone and the content was as following.　It repeated for some times. Does anyone know that it is ?

```
ffff880008b77cb0:  1f1b100b0c6f7807 302d140a09727807   .xo......xr...-0
ffff880008b77cc0:  462061696cfa4a1c 2061726965727265   .J.lia Ferreira 
ffff880008b77cd0:  736f74614d206564 172001e153206520   de Matos e S.. .
ffff880008b77ce0:  726f6968636c656d 6d746f684061735f   melchior_sa@hotm
ffff880008b77d00:  6d746f684061735f 206d6f632e6c6961   _sa@hotmail.com
ffff880008b77d10:  4244303033443633 3630334132313332   36D300DB2312A306
ffff880008b77d20:  4646434544434138 4436363233363046   8ACDECFFF063266D
ffff880008b77d30:  2c33303438323306 20365902c4050b01   .328403,.....Y6
```

Does anyone know what it is ?

Comment: Here is no question. The “answer” would be 42.

Answer (score 0):

The problem "The memory was overwritten" is a very common and difficult problem.

According to my experience, there is some advice shared with you.

1. Look at the memory, there is some relationship with other module?
2. rollback the version, is the problem disappear?
3. cut off some feature, is the problem disappear?
4. rmmod the unnecessary modules, is the problem disapper?
5. does the broken memory always occur in the same place? could we set the attribute of the pace readonly?

The probability and regularity  of occurrence  is always helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Identify the content which overwrite the memory will help to find out who corrupt the memory.